# How I can close Outlook Web Add-in (code to close Outlook Add-in)?

Tags: javascript, outlook, outlook-addin

I have an Outlook web Add-in. On a particular condition I want to close the Add-in.

Comment: Can you please provide some relevant source code and a better explanation of what you're doing currently versus what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [Office.context.ui.closeContainer](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/officeui.closecontainer?product=outlook) method which closes the UI container where the JavaScript is executing.

The behavior of this method is specified by the following:

- Called from a UI-less command button: No effect. Any dialog opened by displayDialogAsync will remain open.
- Called from a task pane: The task pane will close. Any dialog opened by displayDialogAsync will also close. If the task pane supports pinning and was pinned by the user, it will be un-pinned.
- Called from a module extension: No effect.